# After converting MVC 2 to MVC 3 I am getting the: Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

I used Mvc3AppConverter and converted MVC2 to MVC3 and after getting the compilation error of Tag-builder I added the System.Web.WebPages reference, but now I am getting the following web config error :

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter'.

Source Error:

```
 <pages validateRequest="false" pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter" pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl">
 <controls>
     <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your app's root web.config file have an assembly binding redirect for System.Web.Mvc from versions 1.0-2.0 to 3.0?

Also, try using the assembly-qualified type name: "System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"

Comment: Yes it does  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" /> when I add the assembly-qualified type name I get the following error:Could not load file or assembly '"  System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter\, System.Web.Mvc\, Version\=4.0.0.0\, Culture\=neutral\, PublicKeyToken\=31BF3856AD364E35"' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)

Comment: sorry, had a type in there, the version should be 3.0.0.0, not 4.0.0.0

Comment: Thanks. your answer has led to have solved it. I added  <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /> now it is working.